# Clean Kubuntu uninstall/Win10 install

Tags: windows, kubuntu, uninstall

Im using Kubuntu only,my hdd has mounted 400Gb to file system and i cant unmount it to creat new partition so i can boot from windows cd.I want to uninstall completly the Kubuntu OS and install Windows 10
Any help?

Comment: how do you install to the main hdd? can you be more specific. ty

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward, potential BIOS complexities aside.

Backup your user files

Insert Windows 10 Install Media

Install to main HDD

Resize and re-partition from within Windows 10 if needed (it probably isn't)

Discussion: Since you want to "uninstall Kubuntu" you don't have to re-partition anything, you are just going to overwrite everything; Furthermore, Windows has sensitive partition schemes which are best changed with Windows utilities. It is possible you might have to change some BIOS settings, so if you run into trouble with the installation, come back here and we can work it out.

Comment: when i try to boot from the live windows 10 cd nothing happens and i assumed i was doing something wrong(change the BIOS to cd/dvd first)

Comment: are u sure that i dont have to reformat the hdd so windows live cd can recognize it?

Comment: You usually don't have to do that ^

Comment: If you're having trouble booting from another device, try pressing F12 repeatedly (~2 hertz) as the computer first displays anything and stop when you reach the Boot Menu (success) or Kubuntu boot logo (failure).